# 話がすっきり what does this means?

Tags: grammar, meaning, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english, conversations

**話がすっきり** >>What does this means in this context?

2 girl are talking about MC, who was arrested by police. The police suspecting MC is the murderer of a crime.

> G1: 無実なのだから、そのうち帰してもらえるのではないか
>
> G2: 甘い。警察なんて、無理矢理にでも証拠をでっち上げるぐらいするわよ.
>
> てか、そもそも本当にあいつじゃないの？それなら**話がすっきりする**わ

If you can please also give me English translation of the last sentence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

すっきり is a mimetic word that describes how clean or tidy something is. Depending on the context and the subject, すっきりする can mean "to be clear/clean/tidy/simple", "to feel refreshed", etc.

> てか、そもそも本当にあいつじゃないの？
> Um, maybe (the murderer) is actually him in the first place?

> それなら話がすっきりするわ
> [literally] If that (is true), the story would be clear/simple.
> That would clear things up.

<sup>(Of course, this is probably a dirty joke. Is Girl 2 a tsundere character?)</sup>